# <meta name="autosize" content="off" /> - What does it do?

Tags: meta-tags, autosize

I found this meta tag on a website, and I can't figure out exactly what it does. Can't find anything in Google either.

`<meta name="autosize" content="off" />`

Autosize? Which autosize (mobile?) and why would I want it to be `off`?

Comment: meta tags can be anything you want. there's some common "by convention" ones, and then whatever else the site's developer decided on. check the JS code of the site (and maybe the css as well) for any mention of 'autosize'.

Comment: FWIW, the value is not registered at http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions (so for HTML5 it would be invalid).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a remnant of IE6. I instituted it in my own pages years ago with a number of other anti-IE6 tags. Recently found that HTML5 won't validate it. Can't remember what it was for, but found the following comment (original spelling mistake, not mine) in an example I found by Googling:

```
Kill Propietary Image Auto-resize in XP/IE6
```

There's something in the wikipedia entry about IE6 that seems to fit. I'm going to pull it, and suggest that it would be safe for anyone else to do likewise.